# function as template argument in MSVC error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-studio-2015

I stumbled on a weird behavior on MSVC 2015 RC which I'm unable to understand for code that works perfectly on LLVM3.4.

I have a class hierarchy which includes some template classes which accepts non-member function as template arguments, so something like this (I trimmed all the irrelevant code)

```
// .h file
namespace functions {
  float func1(float x) { return 0.0f; }
  float func2(float x) { return 0.0f; }
  float func3(float x) { return 0.0f; }
}

class Base
{
public:
  virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
  virtual ~Base() { }
};

using Func = float(*)(float);

template<Func F, Func I = F>
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  Derived() { }
  ~Derived() { }

  static Derived<F,I>* create();
  Base* clone() const override;
};

using MyDerived = Derived<functions::func1>;
using MyDerived2 = Derived<functions::func2, functions::func3>;

// .cpp file
template<Func F, Func I>
Base* Derived<F,I>::clone() const
{  // <- all errors point here
  return new Derived<F,I>();
}

template<Func F, Func I>
Derived<F,I>* Derived<F,I>::create()
{
  return new Derived<F,I>();
}

template class Derived<functions::func1>;
template class Derived<functions::func2, functions::func3>;
```

Now, this works fine on Clang but on MSVC I got weird errors like

```
C2062: type 'float' unexpected
C2976: 'Derived': too few template arguments
C2955: use of class template requires template argument list
C2910: Derived<F,I>::clone: cannot be explicitly specialized
```

They don't look logical, especially the first error so I'm wondering if it's a MSVC bug or Clang that allows something that shouldn't be allowed even if I didn't find what yet.

These errors look like generated from the explicit instantiation of the template in the source file:

```
template class Derived<functions::func1>;
template class Derived<functions::func2, functions::func3>;
```

Comment: @Jarod42: Sorry, while rewriting the code I introduced that typo but it's not present in original source.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: Shouldn't all definition of methods of class tempaltes be defined in hpp?

Comment: @Barry: I corrected all the typos

Comment: @Zereges that wouldn't affect the compiler; the preprocessor just combines everything into I've file anyway

Comment: Interesting. This compiles without errors in VS2013.

Comment: It also compiles without errors on the latest version of VC++ 2015 on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/.

Comment: @Cameron I tried to compile it by splitting parts of the code (the snipped is part of a larger project) and it compiles fine, I've been able to remove the errors by removing the explicit instantiation of the templates (which forced me to add all methods to header file) but it still gives it when including the header with the main project.